# How to iterate through a JavaScript object to find the parent object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Does anyone know of an efficient way to iterate over a complex javascript object to locate the parent node? I have an object being returned that I am binding to an an [ivhTreeview](https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview?files=1). I can get the object to bind but when I click on an child item I need to derive the parent and grandparent node:

```
root Item/grandparent (Incident)
   - parent (IncidentStartDate)
       -child (2008)
       -child (2009)
       - and so on
```

A sample of the object that I am working with looks like this

```
[
    {
        "label": "Document Type",
        "value": "_oCommon.DocumentType",
        "children": [
            {
                "label": "Incident(4891)",
                "value": "Incident",
                "$$hashKey": "object:84",
                "__ivhTreeviewExpanded": true,
                "selected": true,
                "__ivhTreeviewIndeterminate": false,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "label": "Incident Date",
                        "value": "DateIncidentStart",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "$$hashKey": "object:364",
                                "label": "2008(810)",
                                "value": "01/01/2008"
                            },
                            {
                                "$$hashKey": "object:365",
                                "label": "2009(810)",
                                "value": "01/01/2009"
                            },
                            {
                                "$$hashKey": "object:366",
                                "label": "2010(864)",
                                "value": "01/01/2010"
                            },
                            {
                                "$$hashKey": "object:367",
                                "label": "2011(780)",
                                "value": "01/01/2011"
                            },
                            {
                                "$$hashKey": "object:368",
                                "label": "2012(826)",
                                "value": "01/01/2012"
                            },
                            {
                                "$$hashKey": "object:369",
                                "label": "2013(801)",
                                "value": "01/01/2013"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "$$hashKey": "object:70",
        "__ivhTreeviewExpanded": true,
        "selected": true,
        "__ivhTreeviewIndeterminate": false
    }
]
```

What I am trying to accomplish here is to recursively crawl the tree so that if I click on 2008 I can see the parent was `DateIncidentStart` which is a child element of `DocumentType: Incident`

The approach I took was two for loops, the first one iterates the outter most collection within my angular controller (yes this should be further back in a service but I am just trying to get this work right now)

```
function getAggregateId(selectedNode, parentTree) {
                vm.lastSelectedNode = selectedNode.value;
                vm.lastSelectedNodeId = selectedNode.objectId;
                vm.selectedNodeParent = parentTree;
                //itterate the tree
                for (var p = 0, tree = parentTree.length; p < tree; p++) {
                    //search each child object for the matching key
                    searchTheChildNode(p, parentTree, selectedNode);
                }
            }
```

for the parameters the ivhTreeview will return the selected node and the tree from which that node was selected so in this example below I have both

the node:

```
{
"$$hashKey": "object:364",
"label": "2008(810)",
"value": "01/01/2008"
}
```

and the tree with children objects:

```
[{
   "label": "Incident Date",
    "value": "DateIncidentStart",
    [0] Object
    [1] Object
    [2] Object
    [3] Object
    [4] Object
    [5] Object
    [6] Object
...}]
```

The function searchTheChildNode does the nested loop

```
function searchTheChildNode(index, parent, node) {
    for (var c = 0, child = parent[index].children.length; c < child; c++) {
       for (var nc = 0, items = parent[index].children[c]; nc < items; nc++) {
           if (parent[index].children[c].$$hashKey == node.$$hashKey) {
               console.log('found the parent ' + parent[index].children[c].value);
       }
        }
    }

};
```

Where I am stuck is I can see the loops running but when the condition of $$hasKey is set to true the log even never occurs it just rolls on. I feel there is something syntactically wrong but I can see it.

Does anyone have any suggestions OR is there a better approach to locating the parent and grandparent items when searching a collection like this?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: This is more or less the approach I take in every situation like this.  As far as I know, you're not going to get a more efficient solution with JSON.  I don't know much about this technology so I can't vouch for it, but I have seen mention of LINQ for JavaScript.  https://linqjs.codeplex.com/

Comment: What I found in the internet, if you are going to need to access the parent of a js object from nested object you can save a reference of the parent inside the child.

Comment: Just walk through the object once and add all needed references to children nodes, as @Gonzalo suggested.

Comment: do you have lodash or underscore?

Comment: If you are using nested ng-repeat, then you can bind a function that gets the parent on click. share your html and I will show how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate from the beginning of the tree and iterate over all children. The returned array contains the index of the element and the value from the given key.

```js
function findPath(p, o) {
    function f(o, a) {
        if (Array.isArray(o)) {
            return o.some(function (b, i) {
                if (b[p.key] === p.value) {
                    array = a.concat([i, b[p.key]]);
                    return true;
                }
                return f(b.children, a.concat([i, b[p.key]]));
            });
        }
    }
    var array;
    f(o, []);
    return array;
}

var obj = [{ "label": "Document Type", "value": "_oCommon.DocumentType", "children": [{ "label": "Incident(4891)", "value": "Incident", "$$hashKey": "object:84", "__ivhTreeviewExpanded": true, "selected": true, "__ivhTreeviewIndeterminate": false, "children": [{ "label": "Incident Date", "value": "DateIncidentStart", "children": [{ "$$hashKey": "object:364", "label": "2008(810)", "value": "01/01/2008" }, { "$$hashKey": "object:365", "label": "2009(810)", "value": "01/01/2009" }, { "$$hashKey": "object:366", "label": "2010(864)", "value": "01/01/2010" }, { "$$hashKey": "object:367", "label": "2011(780)", "value": "01/01/2011" }, { "$$hashKey": "object:368", "label": "2012(826)", "value": "01/01/2012" }, { "$$hashKey": "object:369", "label": "2013(801)", "value": "01/01/2013" }] }] }], "$$hashKey": "object:70", "__ivhTreeviewExpanded": true, "selected": true, "__ivhTreeviewIndeterminate": false }];

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(findPath({ key: 'label', value: '2008(810)' }, obj), 0, 4) + '</pre>');        
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(findPath({ key: '$$hashKey', value: 'object:368' }, obj), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```